# While running a MOCK API server in Node.js, getting an error message CANNOT GET /

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, express

I am getting "CANNOT GET/" error message while running a MOCK API server opening my localhost on port 3000 via my browser (http://localhost:3000) using the following index.js file. It's listening to the port at 3000 when I do the `npm start run`. When I try to open the browser it comes up with the error message above. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have tried to replace `const fixtures = require('./data/fixtures');` with `app.use(express.static('./data/fixtures'));` Run `npm install` and `npm start run` but it's still same error. Can someone please help?

```
"use strict";

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 3000;
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const fixtures = require('./data/fixtures');

let fixturesDB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fixtures));

const HTTP_STATUS_CODE_NOT_FOUND = 404;

const getFixtureById = id =>
  fixturesDB.find(fixture => fixture.fixtureId === id);

const getFixtureIndex = id =>
  fixturesDB.findIndex(fixture => fixture.fixtureId === id);

const randomIntBetweenMinMax = (min, max) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;

const secondsToMillis = seconds => seconds * 1000;

const betweenOneAndFiveSecondsInMillis = () =>
  secondsToMillis(randomIntBetweenMinMax(1, 5));

const delayPutAction = fixture =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fixturesDB.push(fixture);
      resolve();
    }, betweenOneAndFiveSecondsInMillis());
  });

const checkIfFixtureExists = fixtureId => getFixtureIndex(fixtureId) !== -1;

const fixtureNotFound = res =>
  res.status(HTTP_STATUS_CODE_NOT_FOUND).send("Fixture not found");

app.get("/fixtures", (req, res) => res.json(fixturesDB));

app.get("/fixture/:id", (req, res) => {
  const fixtureId = req.params.id;
  checkIfFixtureExists(fixtureId)
    ? res.json(getFixtureById(fixtureId))
    : fixtureNotFound(res);
});

app.post("/fixture", async (req, res) => {
  await delayPutAction(req.body);
  res.send("Fixture has been added");
});

app.delete("/fixture/:id", (req, res) => {
  const fixtureId = req.params.id;


  if (checkIfFixtureExists(fixtureId)) {
    fixturesDB = fixturesDB.filter(fixture => fixture.fixtureId !== fixtureId);
    res.send("Fixture has been deleted");
  } else {
    fixtureNotFound(res);
  }
});

app.listen(port, hostname, () => console.log("Server is listening on port 3000"));
```

The url http://localhost:3000 should display the content of the ./fixtures which are the reponse Json data instead of the error message "CANNOT GET/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't have a `'/'` route, hence `CANNOT GET /`. If you want it to point to an existing `'/fixture'` route, you can do something like `app.get('/', (req, res) => res.redirect('/fixtures'))`
2. You *could* use static middleware (although it's not very appropriate in your case):

   - you need to point it to a *directory*, e.g. `app.use('/', express.static('./data/fixtures'))`
   - the files in `./data/fixtures/` directory are made available at the specified route, e.g. `http://localhost:3000/fixtures/list.html` points to `'./data/fixtures/list.html'`
   - you can override a default index file for static middleware, e.g. `app.use('/', express.static('./data/fixtures', {index: 'list.html'}))` will make `http://localhost:3000` show `./data/fixtures/list.html`

Comment: app.get('/', (req, res) => res.redirect('/fixtures')) pointed to the existing '/fixture' as expected. Thanks